# Как работает подписка в приложении Android и как отследить её отключение?

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchases, android-billing

Есть приложение, с возможностью подписки.

Собрал приложение, выгрузил на маркет в формате "бета-версии" и тестирую правильность её работы.

Никак не могу понять, как мне отловить момент, что если пользователь отказался от подписки, то не предоставлять контент, на который он подписывался.

Сделал следующее:

- Зашел в приложение, увидел платный контент, который не доступен без этой самой подписки.
- Подписался "тестовой подпиской", контент разблокировался, всё ок.
- Закрываю приложение - открываю заново и вижу, что приложение проверяет и находит действующую подписку и разрешает платный контент.

Но если я отменяю подписку, то заходя в приложение через час, через два, через три - всё равно проверка завершается тем, что для пользователя доступен контент и подписка всё равно присутствует.

При реализации подписки, использовал библиотеку [Android In-app Billing Version 3](https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3)

Пример кода с главной активности:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BillingProcessor.IBillingHandler {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    public static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    public Timer mTimer;
    public MyTimerTask mMyTimerTask;

    public Timer mTimer2;
    public MyCheckSubscribes mMyTimerTask2;

    protected static final String SUBSCRIPTION_ID = "my_id_subsription";
    private BillingProcessor bp;
    private boolean readyToPurchase = false;

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (!bp.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

    public void buyAdFree() {

        boolean isAvailable = BillingProcessor.isIabServiceAvailable(this);
        if (isAvailable) {
            boolean isSubsUpdateSupported = bp.isSubscriptionUpdateSupported();
            if (isSubsUpdateSupported) {
                bp.subscribe(this, SUBSCRIPTION_ID);
            }
        }
    }


    private void showToast(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        //mCheckout.stop();
        if (bp != null) {
            bp.release();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void showAd() {
        
        if (mTimer != null) {
            mTimer.cancel();
        }

        mTimer = new Timer();
        mMyTimerTask = new MyTimerTask();
        mTimer.schedule(mMyTimerTask, 1000, 3000);
        showToast("Реклама показывается");
    }

    private void hideAd() {

        if (mTimer != null) {
            mTimer.cancel();
        }

        if (mMyTimerTask != null) {
            mMyTimerTask.cancel();
        }

        if (mTimer2 != null) {
            mTimer2.cancel();
        }

        if (mMyTimerTask2 != null) {
            mMyTimerTask2.cancel();
        }

        showToast("Реклама отключена");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBillingInitialized() {
        showToast("onBillingInitialized");
        readyToPurchase = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onProductPurchased(String productId, TransactionDetails details) {

        switch (productId) {
            case SUBSCRIPTION_ID:
                DialogSuccess();
                sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("prem_on", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sharedPreferences.edit();
                ed.putString("PREM_ON", "1");
                ed.apply();
                hideAd();
                break;
        }

        showToast("onProductPurchased: " + productId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBillingError(int errorCode, Throwable error) {
        showToast("onBillingError: " + Integer.toString(errorCode));
    }

    @Override
    public void onPurchaseHistoryRestored() {

        if (mTimer2 != null) {
            mTimer2.cancel();
        }

        if (mMyTimerTask2!=null){
            mMyTimerTask2.cancel();
        }

        mTimer2 = new Timer();
        mMyTimerTask2 = new MyCheckSubscribes();
        mTimer2.schedule(mMyTimerTask2, 100);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        bp = new BillingProcessor(this, getPublicKey(), getMerchantId(), this);
        bp.initialize();

        onPurchaseHistoryRestored();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //
                }
            });
        }
    }

    class MyCheckSubscribes extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (bp.isSubscribed(SUBSCRIPTION_ID)) {
                        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("prem_on", MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sharedPreferences.edit();
                        ed.putString("PREM_ON", "1");
                        ed.apply();
                        hideAd();
                        set_viewp();
                    }

                    if (!bp.isSubscribed(SUBSCRIPTION_ID)) {
                        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("prem_on", MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sharedPreferences.edit();
                        ed.putString("PREM_ON", "0");
                        ed.apply();
                        showAd();
                        set_viewp();
                    }

                    for (String sku : bp.listOwnedSubscriptions())
                        Log.d(TAG, "Owned Subscription: " + sku);
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

Взаимодействие с подпиской происходит после вызова метода `buyAdFree();`

Проверка подписок происходит в методе `onPurchaseHistoryRestored();` который в свою очередь запускает **TimerTask** `MyCheckSubscribes` с условиями на существование/отсутствие подписки и записывает данные в SharedPreferences (либо 1, либо 0) которые мне потом нужны для выявления существования этой самой подписки.

Это всего лишь пример использования, но после отмены купленной подписки, каждый раз заходя обратно в приложение чтобы проверить всё и независимо от того, убивать процесс приложения или нет - контент по подписке остается доступен.

Помогает лишь полная чистка кеша/данных приложения, после которой контент становится не доступен и проверка существования подписки работает должным образом.

Как проверять наличие этой самой подписки и записывать в SharedPreferences действительный и правильный ответ (0-нет или 1-есть).

Такое чувство, что наличие подписки проверяется из какого-то "кеша" и этот неправильный результат записывается в SharedPref , в следствии чего - приложение говорит о том что подписка есть, хотя она отменена уже.

Comment: Да, ответы маркета с подписками-покупками кэшируются. Смотрите документацию - там должен быть метод, принудительно делающий запрос в сеть для получения последних покупок юзера. Там должна будет возвращаться актуальная, а не кэшированная информация